# How can set dynamically value with node-red node

Tags: node-red

There is a node parameter need set a value ShardIterator like follow pic

I want set ShardIterator to a dynamically value ,it will  get value from the previously node，and the previously node output data include input type value

[image: jpg]

How can I resolve this request
ps. the node name is aws kinesis

Comment: I refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44458507/node-red-passing-payload-into-another-nodes-parameters?rq=1  but not work

Comment: Edit the question to give the name of the node you are trying to use.

Comment: @hardillb The node name is AWS kinesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the `{{}}` syntax to override arbitrary configuration options.

Node-RED nodes need to be specifically written to allow for configuration options to be passed in as `msg` properties.

The question you mention in the comments is talking specifically about the `file-out` node which supports using the `msg.filename` property. Without knowing the specific node you are using I can't comment on what options it may allow to be passed in.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,about your mention “Node-RED nodes need to be specifically written to allow for configuration options to be passed in as  msg properties” Is there have any user guide to achieve this？

Comment: Look at the core nodes, e.g. the `file-out` node already mentioned